# Adding Two Factor Verification to Ubuntu Server SSH login

Tags: networking, server, ssh, login, two-factor-authentication

I have an Ubuntu server that I have physical access to and is currently only accessible via the local area network.

I am considering allowing myself to connect remotely and - whilst I realise a properly configured SSH login is already quite secure - I would like to explore additional options for reinforcing security.

With that in mind - is there any method of adding two tier verification to an attempted login via SSH?

Ideally I would imagine this goes along the lines of:

- Login via User@my.server.ip.1
- Initial authentication via public/private key pairs
- Additional prompt for a form of two tier verification, most likely a request for a google auth code paired with my mobile device, but if there was a neat service that could ping me a text or email I'd also be up for that.

Further context:
I am the sole user of this server and will be the only individual using the SSH access.

Bonus question:
Is there any setup to send a notification email/message to an account upon sucessful login?

Comment: there is `pam_google_auth` module which can help you to achieve this behaviour. And I believe it was solved somewhere around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jakuje is on the right track.  A bit of googling let me to an article that gives you exactly what you need.  Just got done setting up my own server to use google authenticator on my phone.  Instead of repeating the directions, here's the URL where I found the answer:

http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/

Comment: Vixter that looks great, I'll give you the answer here and follow up with a summary of the article below in-case that link ever goes dead!